# Exception while deploying the app Glassfish

Tags: maven, jakarta-ee, glassfish, jboss-arquillian, persistence.xml

I am trying example from below and trying to run it in slightly a different way. Pl note I have downloaded the sourcecode from github and then have done some changes as per my requirements
https://samaxes.com/2012/05/javaee-testing-introduction-arquillian-shrinkwrap/

I would like to use Mysql Database and deploy the test on GLassfish server. I have already created database in Mysql named *user* and a table named *usertable* in mysql. When I try to deploy the application on server through "Run -> Run on Server" option, I get following:

```
2017-09-05T13:14:07.015+0200|Information: EclipseLink, version: Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.1.v20150605-31e8258
2017-09-05T13:14:08.045+0200|Warnung: RAR5038:Unexpected exception while creating resource for pool DerbyPool. Exception : javax.resource.spi.ResourceAllocationException: Connection could not be allocated because: java.net.ConnectException: Fehler beim Herstellen der Verbindung zu Server localhost auf Port 1527 mit Meldung Connection refused: connect.
2017-09-05T13:14:08.045+0200|Warnung: RAR5117 : Failed to obtain/create connection from connection pool [ DerbyPool ]. Reason : com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.PoolingException: Connection could not be allocated because: java.net.ConnectException: Fehler beim Herstellen der Verbindung zu Server localhost auf Port 1527 mit Meldung Connection refused: connect.
2017-09-05T13:14:08.045+0200|Warnung: RAR5114 : Error allocating connection : [Error in allocating a connection. Cause: Connection could not be allocated because: java.net.ConnectException: Fehler beim Herstellen der Verbindung zu Server localhost auf Port 1527 mit Meldung Connection refused: connect.]
2017-09-05T13:14:08.045+0200|Schwerwiegend: Local Exception Stack: 
Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.1.v20150605-31e8258): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Error in allocating a connection. Cause: Connection could not be allocated because: java.net.ConnectException: Fehler beim Herstellen der Verbindung zu Server localhost auf Port 1527 mit Meldung Connection refused: connect.
Error Code: 0
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.sqlException(DatabaseException.java:316)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.JNDIConnector.connect(JNDIConnector.java:147)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.DatasourceLogin.connectToDatasource(DatasourceLogin.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.setOrDetectDatasource(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:207)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.loginAndDetectDatasource(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:750)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryProvider.login(EntityManagerFactoryProvider.java:265)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:731)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.getAbstractSession(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:205)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:305)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:337)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:303)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer$2.visitPUD(JPADeployer.java:451)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer$PersistenceUnitDescriptorIterator.iteratePUDs(JPADeployer.java:510)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.iterateInitializedPUsAtApplicationPrepare(JPADeployer.java:492)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.event(JPADeployer.java:398)
    at org.glassfish.kernel.event.EventsImpl.send(EventsImpl.java:131)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:487)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:539)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:535)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:534)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:565)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:557)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:556)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1464)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:109)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1846)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1722)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:534)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:224)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandlerBase.service(StaticHttpHandlerBase.java:189)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Error in allocating a connection. Cause: Connection could not be allocated because: java.net.ConnectException: Fehler beim Herstellen der Verbindung zu Server localhost auf Port 1527 mit Meldung Connection refused: connect.
    at com.sun.gjc.spi.base.AbstractDataSource.getConnection(AbstractDataSource.java:152)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.JNDIConnector.connect(JNDIConnector.java:144)
    ... 53 more
Caused by: javax.resource.spi.ResourceAllocationException: Error in allocating a connection. Cause: Connection could not be allocated because: java.net.ConnectException: Fehler beim Herstellen der Verbindung zu Server localhost auf Port 1527 mit Meldung Connection refused: connect.
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectionManagerImpl.internalGetConnection(ConnectionManagerImpl.java:319)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectionManagerImpl.allocateConnection(ConnectionManagerImpl.java:196)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectionManagerImpl.allocateConnection(ConnectionManagerImpl.java:171)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectionManagerImpl.allocateConnection(ConnectionManagerImpl.java:166)
    at com.sun.gjc.spi.base.AbstractDataSource.getConnection(AbstractDataSource.java:146)
    ... 54 more
Caused by: com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.PoolingException: Connection could not be allocated because: java.net.ConnectException: Fehler beim Herstellen der Verbindung zu Server localhost auf Port 1527 mit Meldung Connection refused: connect.
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.datastructure.RWLockDataStructure.addResource(RWLockDataStructure.java:103)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.ConnectionPool.addResource(ConnectionPool.java:282)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.ConnectionPool.createResourceAndAddToPool(ConnectionPool.java:1512)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.ConnectionPool.createResources(ConnectionPool.java:944)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.ConnectionPool.initPool(ConnectionPool.java:230)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.ConnectionPool.internalGetResource(ConnectionPool.java:511)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.ConnectionPool.getResource(ConnectionPool.java:381)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.PoolManagerImpl.getResourceFromPool(PoolManagerImpl.java:245)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.PoolManagerImpl.getResource(PoolManagerImpl.java:170)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectionManagerImpl.getResource(ConnectionManagerImpl.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectionManagerImpl.internalGetConnection(ConnectionManagerImpl.java:307)
    ... 58 more
Caused by: com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.PoolingException: Connection could not be allocated because: java.net.ConnectException: Fehler beim Herstellen der Verbindung zu Server localhost auf Port 1527 mit Meldung Connection refused: connect.
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.ConnectionPool.createSingleResource(ConnectionPool.java:924)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.ConnectionPool.createResource(ConnectionPool.java:1189)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.datastructure.RWLockDataStructure.addResource(RWLockDataStructure.java:98)
    ... 68 more
Caused by: com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.PoolingException: Connection could not be allocated because: java.net.ConnectException: Fehler beim Herstellen der Verbindung zu Server localhost auf Port 1527 mit Meldung Connection refused: connect.
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.allocator.LocalTxConnectorAllocator.createResource(LocalTxConnectorAllocator.java:110)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.ConnectionPool.createSingleResource(ConnectionPool.java:907)
    ... 70 more
Caused by: javax.resource.spi.ResourceAllocationException: Connection could not be allocated because: java.net.ConnectException: Fehler beim Herstellen der Verbindung zu Server localhost auf Port 1527 mit Meldung Connection refused: connect.
    at com.sun.gjc.spi.DSManagedConnectionFactory.createManagedConnection(DSManagedConnectionFactory.java:129)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.allocator.LocalTxConnectorAllocator.createResource(LocalTxConnectorAllocator.java:87)
    ... 71 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: java.net.ConnectException: Fehler beim Herstellen der Verbindung zu Server localhost auf Port 1527 mit Meldung Connection refused: connect.
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.SQLExceptionFactory40.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.SqlException.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientBaseDataSourceRoot.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.gjc.spi.DSManagedConnectionFactory.createManagedConnection(DSManagedConnectionFactory.java:117)
    ... 72 more
Caused by: org.apache.derby.client.am.DisconnectException: java.net.ConnectException: Fehler beim Herstellen der Verbindung zu Server localhost auf Port 1527 mit Meldung Connection refused: connect.
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetAgent.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetConnection.newAgent_(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.Connection.initConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.Connection.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetConnection.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetConnection40.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.ClientJDBCObjectFactoryImpl40.newNetConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientBaseDataSourceRoot.getConnectionX(Unknown Source)
    ... 74 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:434)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:211)
    at javax.net.DefaultSocketFactory.createSocket(SocketFactory.java:271)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.OpenSocketAction.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.OpenSocketAction.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    ... 82 more
```

My Persistence.xml looks like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">  
    <persistence-unit name="mysql-eclipselink">
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/user" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="admin"/>
        </properties>
   </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

My Pom.xml looks like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.samaxes.javax.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>arquillian-shrinkwrap</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>Arquillian and Shrinkwrap example</name>
    <url>https://github.com/samaxes/java-ee-testing</url>
    <inceptionYear>2012</inceptionYear>
    <organization>
        <name>samaxes</name>
        <url>http://www.samaxes.com/</url>
    </organization>
    <licenses>
        <license>
            <name>The Apache Software License, Version 2.0</name>
            <url>http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt</url>
            <distribution>repo</distribution>
        </license>
    </licenses>

    <developers>
        <developer>
            <id>samaxes</id>
            <name>Samuel Santos</name>
            <url>http://www.samaxes.com/</url>
            <roles>
                <role>project owner</role>
                <role>developer</role>
            </roles>
            <timezone>0</timezone>
        </developer>
    </developers>

    <issueManagement>
        <system>GitHub</system>
        <url>https://github.com/samaxes/java-ee-testing/issues</url>
    </issueManagement>
    <scm>
        <connection>scm:git:git://github.com/samaxes/java-ee-testing.git</connection>
        <developerConnection>scm:git:git@github.com:samaxes/java-ee-testing.git</developerConnection>
        <url>https://github.com/samaxes/java-ee-testing</url>
    </scm>

    <prerequisites>
        <maven>3.0</maven>
    </prerequisites>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${maven.compiler.source}</source>
                    <target>${maven.compiler.target}</target>
                    <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>${project.build.resourceEncoding}</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.20</version>
                <configuration>
                    <skipTests>true</skipTests>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
          <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.19.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>integration-test</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>verify</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>verify</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>jboss-public-repository-group</id>
            <name>JBoss Public Repository Group</name>
            <url>http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian</groupId>
                <artifactId>arquillian-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${arquillian.version}</version>
                <scope>import</scope>
                <type>pom</type>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.23</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-testng-container</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-javaee-6.0</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.3.Final</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
     <profiles>
     <profile>
    <id>glassfish-remote-3.1</id>
    <activation>
        <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
    </activation>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.container</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-glassfish-remote-3.1</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>6.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <testResources>
            <testResource>
                <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
            </testResource>
            <testResource>
                <directory>src/test/resources-glassfish-remote</directory>
            </testResource>
        </testResources>
    </build>
</profile>
    </profiles> 
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.build.resourceEncoding>ISO-8859-1</project.build.resourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.6</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.6</maven.compiler.source>
        <arquillian.version>1.0.1.Final</arquillian.version>
        <jboss.version>7.1.1.Final</jboss.version>
    </properties>
</project>
```

I have not changed any code of src classes or test classes. Could someone pl point out why it is not able to deploy the application ? why would it try to connect to port 1527 on localhost ? My default mysql port is 3306.

I have gone thru the similar post here, but could not solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't configured any data source, so GlassFish is using the default datasource. The default datasource assumes you will use the bundled Derby database which, by default, listens on port `1527`.

[Here is an example MySQL datasource set in a web.xml:](https://github.com/payara/Payara-Examples/blob/master/Payara-Micro/datasource-example/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
     version="3.1">
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <data-source>
     <name>java:global/ExampleDataSource</name>
     <class-name>com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlXADataSource</class-name>
     <server-name>localhost</server-name>
     <port-number>3306</port-number>
     <database-name>mysql</database-name>
     <user>test</user>
     <password>test</password>
    </data-source>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Just to let others know how exactly i solved the problem: I configured Mysql Datasource with guidelines here : http://www.albeesonline.com/blog/2008/08/06/creating-and-configuring-a-mysql-datasource-in-glassfish-application-server/ and then I added <jtd-data-source> in my persistence.xml like this: <jta-data-source>MysqlJNDI</jta-data-source>